# XCode 8.2.1 Unwind Segue Tableview weird bug

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

i am programming my App right now and i am using a **Navigation Controller** inside a **TabBarController**.

Now i have added 2 unwind segues and the first one works perfect, but the second one creates a weird bug. When i load the tableView for the first time it looks everything okay like this:

[Everything looks good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXjIB.png)

And after I return from the childView it looks like this:

[TableView bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Pey.png)

If you touch anywhere the cell just disappears and you can only see a blank view

**I appreciate any help. Thanks !**

**EDIT**

It seems that the error is triggered by the unwind function. Without the segue it does not show the error

Comment: It seems like a problem with the navbar. Did the childViewController do anything with the navbar?

Comment: The childView doesn't but on viewWillAppear I change the title of the NavBar.

Comment: have you tried checking/unchecking **Adjust Scroll View Insets** under Attributes inspector?

Comment: @Maysam yeah I did. The whole navigation stack freaks out. After the cell disappears and I go back it does not show the other views from before. Only the NavigationBar Title changes

Comment: upload you project then.